# PushSharp notification error

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

I keep getting this error when using PushSharp:

```
Waiting for Queue to Finish...
Failure: Apple -> Exception of type 'PushSharp.Apple.NotificationFailureException' was thrown. -> {"aps":{"alert":"Alert Text From .NET!","badge":7,"sound":"default"}}
Queue Finished, press return to exit...
```

Any thoughts?
I use the `DeviceToken` as the long UID shown in iTunes when you pluging your phone. The certificate was exported (Sandbox) as per instruction on PushSharp Wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are using is not the device token. The device token is 32 bytes (which can also be represented as a string of 64 HEX characters). Your iOS application gets it from Apple when it registers for push notifications.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)app {

   // other setup tasks here....

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];

}



// Delegation methods

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken {

    const void *devTokenBytes = [devToken bytes];

    self.registered = YES;

    [self sendProviderDeviceToken:devTokenBytes]; // custom method

}
```